# Migratory aptitude in Baeyer–Villiger reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I found a reaction in which we have to find the product:

[image]

I tried and got to know that it is Baeyer–Villiger reaction but I got confused after seeing the answer, I thought there would be a shift of methyl group according to migratory aptitude, but it is not like that the product is:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 4):

In the following image you can see the charge distribution in the transition state of the Baeyer–Villiger reaction (image taken from Clayden Organic Chemistry):
[image]

As you can see, there is partial positive charge at the migrating C atom, therefore a group will migrate easier if it contains cation stabilizing moieties. A benzene ring significantly stabilizes positive charge in its proximity through delocalization.